# Issue with fixed element - can't make it scrollable

Tags: html, css, sass, angular5

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tmenu" style="direction:rtl;">
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/all.jpg"/>
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/sweets.jpg"/>
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/main meals.jpg"/>
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/ma5bozat.jpg"/>
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/moqblat.jpg"/>
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/mofrznat.jpg"/>
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/carnavals.jpg"/>
  <img src="assets/imgs/menu/other.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Check this image

https://imgur.com/a/hsKax

The images in the top header are the problem. There's about 8 pics.

It shows which fit the width of the screen and hide the rest.

**CSS:**

```
#tmenu
{
    width: max-content;
    overflow-x: scroll!important;
    img
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px!important;
        height: 100px!important;
    }
}
```

How to make it scrollable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#tmenu
{
    width: max-content;
    overflow-x: scroll!important;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    font-size:0
}
    img
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px!important;
        height: 100px!important;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tmenu" style="direction:rtl;">
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/all.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/sweets.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/main meals.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/ma5bozat.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/moqblat.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/mofrznat.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/carnavals.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/imgs/menu/other.jpg"/>
</div>
```

What about this?

Comment: another question - do you know why the empty white spaces between the images is exist ? - I used the chrome developer tools and no padding or margin for the images

Comment: @AboMohsen Edited my answer